# socket.emit is not working under socket.on

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am sending data from client to server like

```
socket.emit('event1', data);
```

this data is received by server perfectly like

```
socket.on('event1', function (data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

but when i am sending data from server to client under this `socket.on` event none of `emit` event is not working only `socket.broadcast.emit` is emitting data to client.js

```
 socket.on('event1', function (data){
    socket.to(data.room).emit('event2', data);             // not working
    io.in(data.room).emit('event2', data);                 // not working
    io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('event2', data);         // not working
    socket.emit('event2', data);                           // not working
    socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('event2', data);   // not working

    socket.broadcast.emit('event2', data);                 // working
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code examples you have shared are missing the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) `,`, which is used to separate function arguments or other terms in a statement or expression.

Here is every example you submitted, with the comma operator included:

```
socket.emit('event1', data);

socket.on('event1', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

socket.on('event1', function (data) {
    socket.to(data.room).emit('event2', data);             // not working
    io.in(data.room).emit('event2', data);                 // not working
    io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('event2', data);         // not working
    socket.emit('event2', data);                           // not working
    socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('event2', data);   // not working

    socket.broadcast.emit('event2', data);                 // working
});
```

Comment: I forgot to write , here but in code i wrote. Now I found the solution about the problem and emit is working fine .Thanks for your accomplishment.